# Parse HTML from javascript-rich website in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, macos, html-parsing

How can I **parse HTML data** from a website **that uses JavaScript** for some of its information. (Some JavaScript code constructs HTML code which I want to use.)

I couldn't find a way to get the HTML data including the HTML data that is loaded by JavaScript in a load time of a second or so. In the *FireBug Lite* browser plugin I can see *all the HTML code including those JavaScript parts*, so it *should be possible* in some way.

**How to do that in a Mountain Lion XCode project**?

(Example site with JavaScript data I want to fetch:
http://www.scorespro.com/basketball/)

Comment: Isn't that possible or why is no one answering? I'm confused ... :(

Comment: I found a PHP library that does exactly what I want – so my current approach is to set up a little app using that library (phantomjs) to get the HTML results I want and fetch those information from within my desktop App – but I couldn't work out the communication between my Mac Application and the phantomjs script. I will post this as an answer to my question, once I worked it out, maybe someone could help? Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497024/how-to-remotely-fetch-answer-of-phantomjs-script-run-on-heroku