# How to remotely fetch answer of phantomjs script run on heroku?

Tags: javascript, html, heroku, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to **fetch some information from a website** using the phantomjs/casperjs libraries, as I'm looking for the **HTML result** after all javascripts on a site are run. I worked it out with the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9978162/1035741):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();  
page.open('http://www.scorespro.com/basketball/', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var p = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
        });
        console.log(p);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

And I also worked it out to get **phantomjs/casperjs running on heroku** by following [these instructions](https://github.com/misza222/heroku-buildpack-casperjs), so when I now say `heroku run phantomjs theScriptAbove.js` on OS X terminal I get the `HTML` of the given basketball scores website as I was expecting.

But what I actually want is to [**get the html text from within a Mac desktop application**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030396/parse-html-from-javascript-rich-website-in-objective-c), this is the reason why I was looking for a way to run the scripts on a web server like heroku. So, my question is:

Is there any way to **get the HTML text** (that my script prints as a result) **remotely within my Objective-C desktop application?**

*Or asked in another way:* how can I **run and get the answer of my script remotely** by using **POST/GET**?

p.s.
I can handle with Rails applications, so if there's a way to do this using Rails - I just need the basic idea of what I have to do and how to get the phantomjs script to communicate with Rails. But I think there might be an even simpler solution ...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you're talking about interprocess communication - so that Phantom's result (the page HTML) can somehow be retrieved by the app.

per the phantom docs, couple options:

- write the HTML to a file and pick up the file in your app
- run the webserver module and do a GET to phantom, and have the phantom script respond with the page HTML

see http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/